# Class is not key value coding-compliant for the key in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a MapKit app with several annotations. When tapped the annotations go to the following page.

[image: Image one]

I want the 'Open in Maps' button to take the co-ordinates from the Annotation and the user's current location (already being tracked) and open the Map application giving directions to the Pin.

I have tried this using the following:

```
 @IBAction func map_button(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let elephant = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.069150, 174.081657)
    let elephant_place = MKPlacemark(coordinate:elephant)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark:elephant_place)
    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:
        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

}
```

But once the MKAnnotation is clicked on it states **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key map_button.**

I have attached my full code paste for the [Info Page/Annotation Segue](http://pastebin.com/5w6Bi1S4) and [Map View](http://pastebin.com/NjAxD5j8)
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: check map_button action in storyboard, it will be disconnected thats y app is crashing. please let me know if you have any issue beside it

Comment: I control dragged it to the IBAction now the button has a Sent Event from Touch Up Inside to View Two map_button, but the app still crashes

Comment: coming same error ?

Comment: Yes still has **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key map_button.**

Comment: please double check ... select File's Owner and click on the "Connection Inspector" (upper right arrow)

Comment: have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v

Comment: I have added image to show connection inspector.

Comment: after tapping on map_button. did you check same thing for next view ?

Comment: What do you mean by check same thing for next view?

Comment: This is the final line for the error: **terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Comment: Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key map_button....   fix ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133136/discussion-between-museer-ansari-and-t-kearsley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, seems you select only map_button. please select View controller and then check in connection inspector. there You may have a bad connection in your Controller. Delete this bad connection and then try

[image]